# What is the preferred console output method in modern D?

Tags: console, d

Most of the D language tutorials I've seen use `printf` to output text to the console, but that can't be right.  I know that D provides direct access to the C/C++ libraries, but shouldn't D's console output function be used instead?  What is the preferred method for outputting text (formatted or otherwise) to a console window?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Within the module `std.stdio`, you'll find `write` and friends: `writeln`, `writef`, and `writefln`.

---

`write` just takes each argument, converts it to a string, and outputs it:

```
import std.stdio;

void main()
{
    write(5, " <- that's five"); // prints: 5 <- that's five
}
```

`writef` treats the first string as a format-specifier (much like C's `printf`), and uses it to format the remaining arguments:

```
import std.stdio;

void main()
{
    writef("%d %s", 5, "<- that's five"); // prints: 5 <- that's five
}
```

The versions ending with "`ln`" are equivalent to the version without it, but also append a newline at the end of printing. All versions are type-safe (and therefore extensible).

Answer (score 1):

The use of `printf` is mostly historical. It has been used because it is declared in one of the modules that is automatically imported and that make the examples shorter. Also, the author of D wrote many of the examples and IIRC, while debugging the compiler he prefers `printf` over `writef` because there is less to go wrong. That plus muscle memory results in `printf` leaking into examples.